# NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable - on hitting the url from browser?

Tags: java, web-applications, httprequest, http-response-codes

i hit the url from browser `http://myMachine/webApp1/customer.do?method=getCustDetail"` . I get the call at server side
 but once i return from server i get the following error in mozilla console i.e

```
 "NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable - `http://myMachine/webApp1/customer.do?method=getCustDetail"`
```

Here is my server code

```
  public String getCustDetail(HttpServletRequest req) {
    req.getSession().removeAttribute("custId");
    return null;
  }
```

i am not getting when i am able to hit the server with above url why i get the  `NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable`  error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening because of some strut 2 interceptor. At least i know rason know and can work on that.

Answer (score 0):

The 503 Service Unavailable error is an HTTP status code that means the web site's server is simply not available right now. Most of the time this is because the server is too busy.

Note: Sites that use Microsoft IIS may provide more specific information about the cause of a 503 Service Unavailable error by suffixing a number after the 503 as in HTTP Error 503.2 - Service Unavailable which means Concurrent request limit exceeded.

Comment: This may have got something to do with the amount of memory the being allocated for the request, and maybe the request needs more memory to successfully execute the request.